# change img src on img click angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I am creating a seat booking system in angularjs. Seats are displayed in a matrix form. And requirement is whenever I select a vacant seat, img src should be changed to selected seat.

Being on learning curve in Angularjs, I am not sure how to achieve this. My HTML to display seat layout is generated dynamically. And I am using directives to embed HTML at runtime. Also using directives to handle the image src change on image click.

Created a plnkr for this :- http://plnkr.co/edit/EemPUIKglSz6j1zQss4i?p=preview

**My HTML**

```
 <body>
    <h1>Compile dynamic HTML</h1>
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
      <textarea ng-model="html"></textarea>
      <div dynamic="html"></div>

    </div>
  </body>
```

**My Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('dynamic', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(html) {
        ele.html(html);
        $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
      });
    }
  };
});

app.directive('change-on-click', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, element,attrs){
          element.bind('click', function(){
                attrs.$set('src', 'C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_sleeper_selected.jpg');
          })
        }
    }
});

function MyController($scope,$sce) {
  $scope.click = function(arg) {
    alert('Clicked ' + arg);
  }
  var str = ["<table frame='box'><tbody>"
, "<tr>"
, "<td><img id=1 title='Avaliable' change-on-click src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img id=4 title='Avaliable' change-on-click src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img id=8 title='Avaliable' change-on-click src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img id=12 title='Avaliable' change-on-click src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img id=16 title='Avaliable' change-on-click src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img id=20 title='Avaliable' change-on-click src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img id=24 title='Avaliable' change-on-click src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img id=28 title='Avaliable' change-on-click src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img id=32 title='Avaliable' change-on-click src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img id=36 title='Avaliable' change-on-click src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img id=40 title='Avaliable' change-on-click src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img id=44 title='Avaliable' change-on-click src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "</tr>"
, "<tr>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=2 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=5 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=9 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=13 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=17 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=21 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=25 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=29 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=33 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=37 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=41 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=45 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "</tr>"
, "<tr>"
, "<td><img title='Not a seat' src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/no_seat.jpg'/></td>"
, "<td><img title='Not a seat' src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/no_seat.jpg'/></td>"
, "<td><img title='Not a seat' src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/no_seat.jpg'/></td>"
, "<td><img title='Not a seat' src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/no_seat.jpg'/></td>"
, "<td><img title='Not a seat' src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/no_seat.jpg'/></td>"
, "<td><img title='Not a seat' src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/no_seat.jpg'/></td>"
, "<td><img title='Not a seat' src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/no_seat.jpg'/></td>"
, "<td><img title='Not a seat' src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/no_seat.jpg'/></td>"
, "<td><img title='Not a seat' src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/no_seat.jpg'/></td>"
, "<td><img title='Not a seat' src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/no_seat.jpg'/></td>"
, "<td><img title='Not a seat' src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/no_seat.jpg'/></td>"
, "<td><img title='Not a seat' id=46 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "</tr>"
, "<tr>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=3 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=6 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=10 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=14 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=18 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=22 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=26 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=30 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=34 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=38 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=42 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=47 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "</tr>"
, "<tr>"
, "<td><img id=Mobile src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_unavailable.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=7 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=11 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=15 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=19 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=23 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=27 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=31 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=35 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=39 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=43 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "<td><img title='Avaliable' change-on-click id=48 src='C:/Users/vk0044682/Desktop/dynamic/dynamic/assets/images/ac_semi_sleeper_vacant.jpg'></img></td>"
, "</tr>"

, "</tbody></table>"];
  $scope.html = $sce.trustAsHtml(str.join(''));

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attribute must be snake-case in your HTML, but camel-case in your directive definition:

```
app.directive('changeOnClick', function () {
```

Comment: Thanks alot for this. Such a small mistake. Thanks again

Comment: Is there any way I can get value of other properies like src or title in my directive?

Comment: You can get them through the attr object (3rd argument passed to your link function): attr.src, attr.title

Comment: thanks again :). I was trying to use attrs.$observe but it was crashing my Chrome browser.  attr.title is working fine.